# async callback: nested $http.get calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an angular factory with an $http.get call to return a promise object with all buses and their depot and area properties.

I am running into classic async request timing issues with the following code. Console.log(allBuses) returns an empty object before console.log(depot) returns the names of the depots in the nested $http.get function.

Without using setInterval or Timeout methods, how do I resolve allBuses object once all buses have been assigned depot and area properties?

```
.factory('busesByDepot', ['$http', 'Camelize', function($http, Camelize){

// get all depot data from depots object
return $http.get('data/depotList.json').success(function(data) {

    allBuses = {};

    data.data.forEach(function(depot){
        var camelName = Camelize.strToCamel(depot.name);
        if(depot.active == true){

            $http.get('data/'+ camelName +'.json').success(function(data) {
                data.forEach(function(d){
                    allBuses[d.num] = {depot: camelName, area: d.area};
                })
                console.log(depot);
            })
        }
    })
    console.log(allBuses);
});

}])
```

Comment: i've deleted my answer since i did not saw the outer `forEach`

Comment: the first solution that comes to my mind is creating a promise and resolving it after the foreach ends

Answer (score 0):

```
.factory('busesByDepot', ['$http', 'Camelize', '$q', function($http, Camelize, $q){
var deferred = $q.defer();
// get all depot data from depots object
$http.get('data/depotList.json').success(function(data) {

    allBuses = {};
    inc = 0;

    data.data.forEach(function(depot){
        var camelName = Camelize.strToCamel(depot.name);
        if(depot.active == true){

            $http.get('data/'+ camelName +'.json').success(function(data) {
                data.forEach(function(d){
                    allBuses[d.num] = {depot: camelName, area: d.area};
                })
                inc++;
                if(inc ==2){
                    deferred.resolve(allBuses)
                };
            })

        }
    })

});

return deferred.promise;

}])
```